# Effect of change of basis on metric representation

Tags: linear-algebra, metric-spaces, change-of-basis

I was reading this question: [Change of basis for linear transformation - Linear algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2560162/change-of-basis-for-linear-transformation-linear-algebra) and the answer gave me a good idea of the effect of change of basis on **representations** of vectors and linear transformations. This got me wondering on how the representation of a metric matrix is affected by a change of basis (or even a general linear transformation). Let's say the metric is $M$ in the canonical basis, and we know its elements explicitly. This means that we know $\langle e_i,e_j\rangle$ explicitly for all $i,j$, where $\{e_i\}$ is the canonical basis (denote it by $\mathcal{A}$).

If we have another basis $\mathcal{B}=\{u_i\}$, the metric representation in the new basis will be $M'$ such that $M'_{ij}=\langle u_i,u_j\rangle$. If we have a change of basis transformation $T$ from $\mathcal{A}$ to $\mathcal{B}$, then I'm not sure if we have enough information to find out $\langle u_i,u_j\rangle$. Using $T$ we can only find the **representation** of $e_i$'s in the $\mathcal{B}$ basis. So I'm a bit confused here on how to deduce $\langle u_i,u_j \rangle$ - (per my understanding, $u_i,u_j$ here are the **new basis vectors** and **not** any specific representations of those).

Would appreciate any help! Thanks

Comment: Use bilinearity of the inner product. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3605473/265466, which looks like a duplicate of this question.

Comment: @amd: Thanks for the hint! I'll attempt it. Another approach that I was thinking of: would it be correct to say that merely changing the basis representation will leave the inner product of any two vectors invariant? In that case, if $\mathcal{A}$ is the initial basis and we change to $\mathcal{B}$ basis, then the inner product of any two vectors will be $v^TMw=v'^TM'w'$, where the unprimed stuff represents basis $\mathcal{A}$ representation and primed corresponds to representations in the $\mathcal{B}$ basis. Does this sound like a reasonable approach to start with or is there a flaw?

Comment: That’s fine, and kudos for recognizing that the inner product per se is independent of the choice of basis! This is a common source of confusion for students who are used to thinking of the Euclidean inner product of two vectors as the dot product of the vectors’ coordinates. That’s only true in an orthonormal basis.